# Lua: Get Locals Outside of Function From A Function

Tags: function, lua, local-variables

I'm wanting to get all locals in the enviroment (debug.getlocal) when i call a certain function (getlenv), but when i call this function it only gets the local variables inside of the function not outside of the function. Is this possible? if so how?

Code i have right now

```lua
function getlenv()
    local i = 1
    repeat
        local k, v = debug.getlocal(1, i)
        if k then
            print(k, v)
            i = i + 1
        end
    until nil == k
end

getlenv()
```

Comment: The first argument of `debug.getlocal` is a level in the stack (try to replace 1 with 2, 3,...)

Comment: oh thanks.. i feel stupid now, yet i cant mark a comment as an answer

Comment: @Cosmic Never add answer to question, post it as an answer instead. Self-answering is perfectly fine, while adding answers into question body is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i was just being dumb, just had to change 
`local k, v = debug.getlocal(1, i)` 
to 
`local k, v = debug.getlocal(2, i)` 
to get the locals outside of the function o_0